# python verify multiple keys Boolean in dictionary

Tags: python

If I have some dictionaries:

```
data1 = {'setpoint': '366', 'Weekdays': 'True', 'Weekends': 'True', 'starttime': '10:40', 'endtime': '11:40'}
data2 = {'setpoint': '366', 'Weekends': 'True', 'starttime': '10:40', 'endtime': '11:40'}
data3 = {'setpoint': '366', 'starttime': '10:40', 'endtime': '11:40'}
```

where I am trying create Boolean statement for if these keys exist `Weekends` or `Weekdays` or not, can someone give me a better way of doing this?

`keys_to_verify = ['Weekends', 'Weekdays']`

This below will return `True`:

```
in_dictionary = all(key in data1 for key in keys_to_verify)

print(in_dictionary)
```

This will return `False` obviously:

```
in_dictionary = all(key in data3 for key in keys_to_verify)

print(in_dictionary)
```

But this return `False` as well like I am missing something, any tips greatly appreciated.

```
in_dictionary = all(key in data2 for key in keys_to_verify)

print(in_dictionary)
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `any` instead of `all`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the last condition returns False because not **all** of the keys are in there
if you don't need all of them in there use **any**

```
in_dictionary = any(key in data2 for key in keys_to_verify)
print(in_dictionary)
>> True
```

But you may also want to know **which** is in there, then I would do it like this:

```
def find(verify, dct):
    is_in = []
    for key in verify:
        if key in dct: is_in.append(key)
    return is_in

find(keys_to_verify, data1)
['Weekends', 'Weekdays']   # -> in an if statement this would evaluate to True
find(keys_to_verify, data2) 
['Weekends']               # -> this, too
find(keys_to_verify, data3)
[]                         # -> and this to False
```

Comment: Thanks ill hit the green check